# Remove characters from text file when appending strings with backspaces

Tags: c#, .net, text-files, streamwriter, backspace

Is it possible to append a string containing backspaces to a text file and treat all the backspaces in it as a "remove last char" operation?

E.g. My text file:

> This file has
>
> two lines

Some sort of C# code like this:

```
string str = "...\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b one line."
myFile.Append(str);
```

And after executing this code, the text file looks like this:

> This file has one line.

The `StreamWriter` and the `File` classes don't seem to help much.

I could not figure out an optimal way to implement this without reading and writing the whole file on every single append operation, which would probably lead to terrible performance issues for large text files. The idea is to intensively write log statements to a text file with this new feature.

My second concern is how to deal with windows-style new line characters ("\r\n")? i.e. one backspace should remove a whole single newline character sequence ("\r\n").

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Source code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you just want to delete the last n characters of a file before appending to it?

Comment: Not actually, the string may contain characters before the backspaces occur in it. As in the provided example, there are three dot (.) characters in the beginning of the string. But the string will indeed always be appended to the text file. (I've edited the example to let it clear)

Comment: The short answer is no.. The long answer is you will have to build the functionality your self using a `FileStream` of some description `Position` or `Seek`, and some good old fashioned coding

Comment: @TheGeneral Probably more complex than using a `FileStream` considering the encoding :-) (see for example the nick used by the questioner). Sadly there is no unified `StreamReaderWriter` in .NET, so it becomes a pain modifying an encoded text file.

Comment: @xanatos very good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [xanatos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51399129/823321), and on [TheGeneral's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398236/remove-characters-from-text-file-when-appending-strings-with-backspaces#comment89768279_51398236), I wrote this prototype `FileLogger` class, which evaluates the string (to be appended) into a sequence of initial backspace characters plus a remaining string (without any backspaces).

In case there are initial backspaces, the program truncates the `FileStream` object based on the number of initial backspaces (in a very naïve way), and then appends the remaining string.

Unfortunately, this solution does NOT consider any `\r\n` newline sequence which should be be removed by a single backspace, both from the `FileStream` and from the appended string. As it is right now, two backspaces are required to remove a single windows-style newline character sequence.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Example
{
    public static class FileLogger
    {
        public static bool IsStarted { get; private set; }
        public static Encoding Encoding { get; private set; }
        public static string LogFilePath { get; private set; }

        private static FileStream FS;
        private static int BytesPerChar;
        private static readonly object Locker = new object();

        public static void Start(string logFilePath, Encoding encoding = null)
        {
            lock (Locker)
            {
                if (IsStarted) return;
                LogFilePath = logFilePath;
                Encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
                if (File.Exists(LogFilePath)) File.SetAttributes(LogFilePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
                FS = new FileStream(LogFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, FileOptions.RandomAccess);
                FS.SetLength(0);
                FS.Flush();
                BytesPerChar = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(new[] { 'A' });
                IsStarted = true;
            }
        }

        public static void Close()
        {
            lock (Locker)
            {
                if (!IsStarted) return;
                try { FS?.Close(); } catch { }
                FS = null;
                IsStarted = false;
            }
        }

        public static void WriteToFile(string text)
        {
            lock (Locker)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return;

                if (!text.Contains('\b'))
                {
                    FS.Position = FS.Length;
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetBytes(text);
                    FS.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    FS.Flush();
                    return;
                }

                // Evaluates the the string into initial backspaces and remaining text to be appended:
                EvaluateText(text, out int initialBackspaces, out string remainingText);

                // If there are no initial backspaces after evaluating the string, just append it and return:
                if (initialBackspaces <= 0)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(remainingText)) return;

                    FS.Position = FS.Length;
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetBytes(remainingText);
                    FS.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    FS.Flush();
                    return;
                }

                // First process the initial backspaces:
                long pos = FS.Length - initialBackspaces * BytesPerChar;
                FS.Position = pos > 0 ? pos : 0;
                FS.SetLength(FS.Position);

                // Then write any remaining evaluated text:
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remainingText))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetBytes(remainingText);
                    FS.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
                FS.Flush();
                return;
            }
        }

        public static void EvaluateText(string text, out int initialBackspaces, out string remainingTextToAppend)
        {
            initialBackspaces = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char ch in text)
            {
                if(ch == '\b')
                {
                    if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Length--;
                    else initialBackspaces++;
                }
                else sb.Append(ch);
            }
            remainingTextToAppend = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
FileLogger.Start("test.log");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("aaa\r\n");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("bbbb");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("\b");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("\b\b");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("\b\b\b\b");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("XXX");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("\b\bYY\bZ");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
FileLogger.WriteToFile("Done!");
FileLogger.Close();
```

Output (test.log file):

> aaXYZ

Answer (score 6):

Doing it "correctly" in the "most general case" is *very very*, **very** difficult. There is no direct support in .NET. Let's see the state of the art:

- There is a `FileStream` class... It is read/write. Sadly it doesn't know about encoding and it works in bytes. So no UTF-8 and no Unicode natively. You see your beautiful nick `sɐunıɔןɐqɐp`? It clearly needs some encoding :-)
- `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` can be "connected" to a `FileStream`... Sadly they are separate (one is only read, one is only write), and sadly they pre-buffer, so that the `FileStream.Position` doesn't correspond to the currently "read" character in `StreamReader`. This makes reading with `StreamReader` and then doing corrections "in place" with `StreamWriter` quite complex.
- Even if we had a `StreamReaderWriter`, it would be a little difficult. .NET works with UTF-16 `char`s, so that many Unicode characters (emoji like  [grinning face](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f92a/index.htm) for example) are composed of two `char`... So a single `\b` would probably need to erase one or two `char` (and between 1 and 4 bytes in UTF-8), depending on what it finds.
- Note that more complex emojis (like  [‍‍  family](https://emojipedia.org/family-man-man-girl-girl/) ) are composed by multiple single emojis (4 unicode codepoints, corresponding to 11 .net `char`, corresponding to 25 bytes in UTF-8), but we will ignore this problem

The simplest solution is to load the whole file in memory inside a `string` (or similar), modify it, and then re-write it to disk. And even here, beware of the end-of-line, that could be two characters (`\r\n`), while "logically" they are a single character (if you are at the beginning of a line in notepad and press a single backspace, it will erase completely `\r\n`). But as you've noted this solution is "slow" :-)

Other solution, with many limitations. As I've written in a comment, you could do the opposite: save the `Position` before writing, write, if you need to correct change the `Position` back, re-write, `SetLength()` to truncate the excess file if present. This limits the problem to cases where you can only modify the textual part you've written in the current session, and in general you can only modify the "last" part of the file.

```
public static long WriteAppend(this FileStream fs, string str, Encoding enc)
{
    long pos = fs.Length;
    fs.Position = pos;
    byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(str);
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return pos;
}


public static long RewriteTruncate(this FileStream fs, long pos, string str, Encoding enc)
{
    fs.Position = pos;
    byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(str);
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    fs.SetLength(pos + bytes.Length);
    return pos;
}
```

Use:

```
int secs = 5;

using (var fs = new FileStream("Hello.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    fs.WriteAppend("Beginning of the elaboration\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);

    long pos1 = fs.WriteAppend("Step 1\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);
    long pos2 = fs.WriteAppend($"Working 0\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(secs * 1000);
        fs.RewriteTruncate(pos2, $"Working {i}\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(secs * 1000);
    fs.RewriteTruncate(pos1, $"Finished working\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Keep open the output file in Notepad++ and refresh it every few seconds.

Comment: The most bizarre part is that there are so many points to consider, but even a non-IT person would understand what I'm trying to achieve here :-)

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp You could do the opposite: save the `Position` *before* writing, write, if you need to correct change the `Position` back, re-write, `SetLength` to truncate the excess file if present. This limits the problem to cases where you can only modify the textual part you've written in the current session, and in general you can only modify the "last" part of the file.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot xanatos, I've shared some code which was implemented based on this answer. Although many features you've pointed out are still not covered by the code, it does provides a good basis to start with.